# c# how to add class to a list from an array of classes

Tags: c#, arrays, list, class, templates

I have a class to define for example a ship, then I have an array of the class with some default parameters But later on I want to be able to add to a list of the class using one of the pre defined examples. I don't know how to add the predefined class to the list at the same time creating a copy of it and not a pointer to the original array. Here is the code to hopefully make it all clear.

```
   public enum ShipType
    {
      Capital,
      Cruiser,
      Frigate,
      Fighter,
      Colony,
      NumShipTypes
    }
    public class Ship
    {
      public Vector3 ShipPosition;
      public ShipType Type;
      public string DesignName;
      public Ship(ShipType type,string designame)
      {
        Type = type;
        DesignName = designame;
        ShipPosition = Vector3.zero;
      }
    }
```

Then my array of default types:-

```
public Ship[] AllShips = new Ship[(int)ShipType.NumShipTypes]
  { 
    new Ship(ShipType.Capital,"MassiveOne"),
    new Ship(ShipType.Cruiser,"MediumOne"),
    new Ship(ShipType.Frigate,"SmallerOne"),
    new Ship(ShipType.Fighter,"TinyOne"),
    new Ship(ShipType.Colony,"Mayflower")
  };
```

Now I create a list and heres where I want to add a copy of one of the above:-

```
public List<Ship> FleetShips = new List<Ship>(); 

FleetShips.Add(AllShips[(int)ShipType.Fighter]);
```

But this seems to just add a reference or pointer to the one in the array. What I need is something like this, but that actually works:-

```
FleetShips.Add(new AllShips[(int)ShipType.Fighter]());
```

but this give me "is a field but is used like a type" error

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your class implement the [`ICloneable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icloneable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) interface and implement your own `Clone()` method.

Then when you want to add it to your collection you can do this

```
FleetShips.Add((Ship)AllShips[(int)ShipType.Fighter].Clone());
```

Comment: Thanks I went with this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to add a copy-constructor to your Ship-class.

```
public class Ship
{
  public Vector3 ShipPosition;
  public ShipType Type;
  public string DesignName;
  public Ship(ShipType type,string designame)
  {
    Type = type;
    DesignName = designame;
    ShipPosition = Vector3.zero;
  }
  //copy-constructor
  public Ship(Ship other)
  {
    Type = other.Type;
    DesignName = other.DesignName;
    ShipPosition = Vector3.zero;
  }
}
```

when you want add a copy of the ship you do

```
FleetShips.Add(new Ship(AllShips[(int)ShipType.Fighter]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement ICloneable.

```
   public class Ship: ICloneable
    {
        public Vector3 ShipPosition;
        public ShipType Type;
        public string DesignName;
        public Ship(ShipType type, string designame)
        {
            Type = type;
            DesignName = designame;
            ShipPosition = Vector3.zero;
        }


        public object Clone()
        {
           return this.MemberwiseClone();
        }
    }
```

Add

```
FleetShips.Add(AllShips[(int)ShipType.Fighter].Clone() as Ship);
```

Edit: Could still be a problem depending on what Vector3 is though

Comment: Thanks, I went with this version as I have a lot more stuff in the ship class and this seemed far less typing! Thanks for the example too, I'm still new to the more complex parts of c# (come from C background)

Comment: You're welcome. But note that this only creates a shallow copy of the object. If you have any reference types they are still shared.